# How to run a kivy script in the kivy VM?

Tags: android, python, virtual-machine, kivy, ubuntu

So I am looking into using Kivy for Android development. Defeating the jedi etc.

But I have hit a roadblock! I installed the Kivy VM image in VirtualBox, but when I try to run the test script:

```
# /usr/bin/kivy
__version__ = 1.0
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Hello(App):
    def build(self):
        btn = Button(text='Hello World')
        return  btn

Hello().run()
```

Using:
python main.py

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named kivy.app
```

Comment: Not the reason for your problem, but `# /usr/bin/kivy` should be `#! /usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried just plain installing kivy as they say to on their website, and it worked.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
apt-get install python-kivy
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a file named kivy.py in the same folder as main.py?

try

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
print kivy.__file__
```

Comment: what happens if you type `/usr/bin/kivy` ?

Comment: When I use ls in /usr/bin/ I see kivy in red, but I can't cd or find it in the file manager.

Comment: use ls -l to see where its trying to point .... and then use `locate fname` to find it... your problem seems to be an incorrectly installed kivy ... are you sure you just used the image they offer?

Comment: Yeah I just downloaded the vm image. It has the kivy background and everything! Is it best for you to just TV into my machine?

Comment: I installed kivy manually, which I found weird that I had to do. But now when I run buildozer I get  "raise ExceptionPexpect ('The command was not found or was not executable: %s.' % self.command)"